# calculating a weighted daily average for each DOY in xarray across a decade

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, python-xarray

I have a few years of sea level height data with variables of both absolute height and sea level anomaly. I want to calculate an improved anomaly dataset that takes into account seasonal changes in absolute height. Towards that goal I'm trying to calculate the mean height at every point on the grid for each day of the year. Ideally I'd like to take into account the previous two weeks and following two weeks with the closer days carrying more weight in the final mean. I think a normal distribution of weights would be ideal. There is a nice [example in the `xarray` documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/monthly-means.html) of how to calculate seasonal averages, but I've yet to find a suitable approach for this weighted mean of each day.

My initial `ds` looks like:

[image]

I'm able to calculate this daily average via:

`ds_daily_avg = ds.groupby('time.dayofyear').mean(dim='time')`

The output of `ds_daily_avg`
[image]

but there is too much variation in the daily averages because I only have a decade of data. I've thought of then just doing a rolling average of ~ 14 days and while *good enough* this doesn't properly do the weighting I'm hoping to implement:

`ds_daily_avg.sla.rolling(dayofyear=14).mean()`

Any advice for properly doing this weighted mean through time?

Comment: Can you print ds_daily_avg and share the output? Do you used the test data?

Comment: Sure thing @dl.meteo I just added that output. I wish I could easily share the data but it is ~500 MB I downloaded from https://resources.marine.copernicus.eu. Basically it 5 years of data from the Gulf Stream region.

Comment: The example by xarray works fine for the test data. What are you looking for?

Comment: Have a look at `rolling_exp`. Also `rolling(dayofyear=14).construct("doy_window")` may be of interest (you can than use `weighted(weights).mean()`). The problem is that there is currently no way create periodic boundary for rolling (https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2007).